# F# sequences returning one item at a time

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am new to F# and I am trying to convert a DbDataReader class from c# to F#,  the DBDataReader reads and returns a csv line as a list

```
member this.ReadCSV = 
    seq { 
        use textReader = File.OpenText(filename)
        while (not textReader.EndOfStream) do
            let line = textReader.ReadLine()
            // linedata is a class variable that holds the current data for use by DBDataReader
            linedata <- line |> Seq.toList |> splitDelimited delimiter "" [])
            yield true
        yield false
    }
```

the DBDataReader class has a Read() function that when called should move the cursor to the next line in the input, i implemented this using an index variable as below but this seems inefficient when processing a file with millions of rows.  is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
override this.Read() =
    let hasRows = Seq.item idx this.ReadCSV
    idx <- idx + 1
    hasRows
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Csv Type Provider?

https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

Comment: i have looked into the CSV type provider but it has the same issue in that the DBDataReader class requires that the Read function advance the read pointer to the next record,  i can'f find a simple way of doing that with sequences in F#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an Enumerator instead of a Sequence?

If you really want to use a Sequence in FP style, then

1. yield option values from the sequence and
2. replace the loop statement that uses `this.Read()` method with a for..in expression that uses `this.ReadCSV` as the enumerable-expression and

```
member this.CSV = 
    seq { 
        use textReader = File.OpenText(filename)
        while (not textReader.EndOfStream) do
            let line = textReader.ReadLine()
            yield (line |> Seq.toList |> splitDelimited delimiter "" [])
    }


for linedata in this.CSV do
    ...
```

Comment: thanks but the read() function is used by an external program and i have no control over that.

Comment: In that case, you could cast the sequence as an IEnumerator (e.g., `member this.CSV = (seq { ...}).GetEnumerator()`) and use enumerators `MoveNext()` and `Current` to implement the `Read()` method.